# Facing Problem In EasyEDA

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eda

[image]

I can't find the SMT type option in EasyEDA. Is it a new update or I messed up something? And what is a paste type? Please someone help me on getting the SMT type option back. There is no resource related to it on google, so I have asked here.

Comment: TQFP is SMT, so it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: The 'paste type'  option was not there. There was an 'SMT type' option. It showed either a component is basic or extended. The extended components can be placed a maximum of 20 on a board. Now I can not see it.